# How to assign unique key to values using array_agg() function in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to assign key to each distinct value in bigquery with row_number. But it is giving resource exceeding error. So can I achieved same thing with array_aggegate function?

code :

```
select a.values 
    , a.type
    , max_key + row_number() over(order BY a.values) key
    , a.event_date
    from gaid_raw a
    LEFT JOIN  existing_key_table e
    on  e.type = a.type
    and e.values = a.values
    left join (
      select type, coalesce(max(key),0) max_key from existing_key_table group by 1
    ) e1
    on e1.type = a.type
    where e.key is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but I think this is the logic you want:

```
select gr.values, gr.type
       coalesce(max_key, 0) + row_number() over (partition by gr.type order by gr.values) as key,
       gr.event_date
from gaid_raw gr left join
     (select type, max(key) as max_key
      from existing_key_table
      group by 1
     ) e
     on e.type = gr.type
where not exists (select 1
                  from existing_key_table e
                  where e.type = gr.type and e.values = gr.values
                 );
```

For unrecognized types, you need the `coalesce()` in the outer `select`, not the subquery.

You also seem to want to assign sequential numbers based on the type.

If you still get resource errors, there is a way to fix this, but a bit more information is needed about the data.  However, I have in the past used random values for such keys -- assuming the ordering is not needed.  There is such a small chance of collision that it has worked on fairly large data.

Now, I would use `GENERATE_UUID()` for a unique id.